# What's the use of GIT Checkout command?

Tags: git, version-control

Have a little question on GIT

What's the real use of command 'git checkout'?

When 'Person A' checks out file 'abc.c', does it mean that 'Person B' cannot edit that file ?

I can use 'git clone' and edit the file.  Where do I need 'git checkout'?

Please explain

Answer (score 1):

Git "checkout" is for switching between branches in your local repo.

> When 'Person A' checks out file 'abc.c', does it mean that 'Person B' cannot edit that file ?

No.  Checkout is a purely local operation.

Git does not have any way to "lock" a file to prevent someone else editing it.  That would be contrary to the Git distributed version control model .... and impossible to implement.